# No such table when creating the public user accounts by Mezzanine for Django web dev

Tags: python, django, mezzanine

I followed the guideline on the official website of [Mezzanine](http://mezzanine.jupo.org/docs/user-accounts.html) as follows

In `myapp/models.py`:

```
from django.db import models

class MyProfile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField("auth.User")
    date_of_birth = models.DateField(null=True)
    bio = models.TextField()
```

In `settings.py`:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = (
    "myapp",
    "mezzanine.accounts",
    # Many more
)

ACCOUNTS_PROFILE_MODEL = "myapp.MyProfile"
```

But it says that:

> django.db.utils.OperationalError: no such table: myapp_myprofile.

The signup page shows what I want, i.e., date of birth and the bio. But once I clicked the signup button, the error happened.

Am I missing something? Shall I also add something in the views.py file?

Answer (score 1):

You need to create the migrations to your new app (myapp)

`python manage.py makemigrations myapp`

This will output:

> - Create model MyProfile

Then migrate:

```
python manage.py migrate
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to create the correspondent table in your database.

To do that run in your terminal:

```
python manage.py makemigrations
```

then

```
python manage.py migrate
```

Comment: Thanks. I tried what you said.  `python manage.py makemigrations` gives me that `No changes detected` and `python manage.py migrate` gives me that `no migrations to apply`. I even deleted the dev.db file and get a new database by `python manage.py createdb`. Finally, I still got the same error `django.db.utils.OperationalError: no such table: myapp_myprofile.`

Comment: `myproject/
├── __init__.py
├── deploy
├── dev.db
├── fabfile.py
├── manage.py
├── moderna
├── myproject
├── requirements.txt
├── static
└── theme`
A more deep structure is here: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B20Tyrbv7PCGWU9JQ0tGd2tQX2s/view?usp=sharing